# Help with cloning method

Tags: java

I'm almost done with this project which involves converting between Celsius, Fahrenheit, and Kelvin and the last thing I need is to figure out the cloning method. The task is **"clone, which takes no formal parameters and returns a reference to a newly created Temperature object that has the same value and scale as the object of which it is a clone "**. My code compiles, but when run in the client program, i recieve an error of **java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Temperature.clone(Temperature.java:134)**

```
public class Temperature {
    private double value;
    private String scale;

    public Temperature() { // default constructor 
        this.value = 0;
        this.scale = "C";
    }

    public Temperature(double value, String scale) {
        this.value = value;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getScale() {
        return this.scale;
    }

    public double getCelsius() {

        if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            return this.value;
        } else if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            double faren = ((this.value - 32) * (5 / 9));
            return faren;
        } else {
            double kelvin = (this.value - 273.15);
            return kelvin;
        }
    } // end getCelcius

    public double getFaren() {
        if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            return this.value;
        } else if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            double celsius = ((this.value * 1.8) + 32);
            return celsius;
        } else {
            double kelvin = ((this.value * 1.8) - 459.67);
            return kelvin;
        }
    } // ene getFaren

    public double getKelvin() {
        if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) {
            return this.value;
        } else if (scale.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            double celsius = (this.value + 273.15);
            return celsius;
        } else {
            double faren = ((this.value + 459.67) * (5 / 9));
            return faren;
        }
    } // end getKelvin

    public void setTemperature(Temperature t) {
        this.value = t.value;
    }

    public void setType(double degree, String measure) {
        this.value = degree;
        this.scale = measure;
    }

    public void setValue(double degree) {
        this.value = degree;
    }

    public void setScale(String measure) {
        this.scale = measure;
    }

    public double convertToCelsius() {
        this.scale = "C";
        return this.value = getCelsius();
    }

    public double convertToFaren() {
        this.scale = "F";
        return this.value = getFaren();
    }

    public double convertToKelvin() {
        this.scale = "K";
        return this.value = getKelvin();
    }

    public Temperature clone() {
        this.value = value;
        this.scale = scale;
        return clone();
    }
}
```

The cloning method is the last method, so any help would really be appreciated. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong! This is my first time using this website, so apologies for the formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Temperature clone()
{
    return new Temperature(this.value, this.scale);
}
```

That's all you should need.  The method you wrote simply assigned the fields of the calling object to themselves, and then calls itself.  Eventually it overflows the stack with calls to itself without having really done anything.

Comment: This is homework, thus I would think a direct source code copy-paste answer is not the ideal way to approach this.

Comment: Unless Temperature is and always will be a `final` class, this is incorrect behavior. Imagine I have a UiTemperature class that adding UI-related behavior. Calling clone on a UiTemperature instance should not result in a vanilla Temperature.

Comment: True: if you override the  clone method in a nonfinal class, you should return an object obtained by invoking super.clone. Take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf), page 45.

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to give you the answer to a homework project, that's frowned upon. However, the problems with your clone() method are hard to be... vague about.

```
public Temperature clone()
```

The method header looks great. You're returning a Temperature type, it's publicly accessible.

```
this.value = value;
this.scale = scale;
```

Do you know what the 'this' keyword does? It refers to the object that the method is called on. So, if I have a Temperature object 'a' and I want to call a.clone(), this will set a's value equal to... a's value.

```
return clone()
```

Here's the part that shows your big problem. What are you actually telling java to do here? You're telling it to **return** whatever the clone() method returns. Which means that clone will call itself, which will again call itself... on to stack overflow. This is a recursive loop that can't exit.

Remember, you want clone() to **return** a **new** Temperature object.

Comment: Well written answer. Gives some hints on what is being done wrong, a few hints on how to fix it without giving away to much. +1

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally made `clone()` a recursive method without a means of terminating.

Also, [`Object.clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) will only return a *shallow* copy. If you're attempting to return a *deep* copy, I'd recommend using a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).

Comment: this object has no fields that are non-primitive and mutable, so the regular clone is appropriate.

Comment: Dilum is correct, a shallow copy is sufficient because value is a primitive and scale is a reference to an immutable object (String).

Comment: True, anyway, a copy constructor isn't the right way to create the new instance since the class is not final. You have to rely on super.clone. In fact, if you override the clone method in a nonfinal class, you should return an object obtained by invoking super.clone.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a stack overflow is because of this line:

```
return clone();
```

Have you learned about recursion yet? This line is calling the clone method from *inside* the clone method... which keeps happening over and over and over... well, until the stack runs out of space!

You want to return a new object, rather than returning `clone()`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything to primitive fields and fields of immutable types (like `scale`). So you are doing too much in your `clone()`. Calling to super and Cloneable are also needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Object`'s [clone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method you **must** implement [Clonable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface.

According to documentation

> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the Cloneable interface results in the exception CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.

```
public class Temperature implements Clonable // just this will work for your requirement
{
    // other code

    public Temperature clone() {
        return super.clone() //this will server your purpose of cloning your temperature object.
    }

}
```

But its not a good idea to follow this way. Its better to create a new instance from this object.

The reason for StackOverflowError is, you are calling your `clone` method repeatedly, which will never return.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, `clone()` is not the way to go.  Obviously, if your instructor requires it than you have to write it and include `implements Clonable`.

Otherwise it is often simpler to write a copy constructor:

```
public Temperature(Temperature original) { ... }
```

which builds a new `Temperature` instance from an old `Temperature` instance.  That has the same effect as `clone()` but can avoid some of the associated problems.

For extra credit, have you done `enum` yet?  If so then you might want to look at using an `enum` here.